# Converting from a repository factory to an IOC solutions for EF?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection, unity-container, entity-framework-6

I have an application which borrows a lot of code from the John Papa Code Camper application. In his applicatione he uses a Repository factory to provide a new repository or an existing repository if one already exists in cache. To me this seems overly complicated and I am wondering if I could use Unity to do the same thing.  Here's an example of the code that I am currently using:

In the UOW he has this code to get the repos:

```
    public IRepository<Answer> Answers { get { return GetStandardRepo<Answer>(); } }
```

This code to call the repository provider:

```
    protected IRepositoryProvider RepositoryProvider { get; set; }

    protected IRepository<T> GetStandardRepo<T>() where T : class
    {
        return RepositoryProvider.GetRepositoryForEntityType<T>();
    }
    protected T GetRepo<T>() where T : class
    {
        return RepositoryProvider.GetRepository<T>();
    }
```

The following respository provider:

```
public class RepositoryProvider : IRepositoryProvider
{
    public RepositoryProvider(RepositoryFactories repositoryFactories)
    {
        _repositoryFactories = repositoryFactories;
        Repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    }

    //public RepositoryProvider(RepositoryFactories repositoryFactories)
    //{
    //    _repositoryFactories = repositoryFactories;
    //    Repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    //}

    /// <summary>
    /// Get and set the <see cref="DbContext"/> with which to initialize a repository
    /// if one must be created.
    /// </summary>
    public DbContext DbContext { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get or create-and-cache the default <see cref="IRepository{T}"/> for an entity of type T.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">
    /// Root entity type of the <see cref="IRepository{T}"/>.
    /// </typeparam>
    /// <remarks>
    /// If can't find repository in cache, use a factory to create one.
    /// </remarks>
    public IRepository<T> GetRepositoryForEntityType<T>() where T : class
    {
        return GetRepository<IRepository<T>>(
            _repositoryFactories.GetRepositoryFactoryForEntityType<T>());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get or create-and-cache a repository of type T.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">
    /// Type of the repository, typically a custom repository interface.
    /// </typeparam>
    /// <param name="factory">
    /// An optional repository creation function that takes a DbContext argument
    /// and returns a repository of T. Used if the repository must be created and
    /// caller wants to specify the specific factory to use rather than one
    /// of the injected <see cref="RepositoryFactories"/>.
    /// </param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Looks for the requested repository in its cache, returning if found.
    /// If not found, tries to make one using <see cref="MakeRepository{T}"/>.
    /// </remarks>
    public virtual T GetRepository<T>(Func<DbContext, object> factory = null) where T : class
    {
        // Look for T dictionary cache under typeof(T).
        object repoObj;
        Repositories.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out repoObj);
        if (repoObj != null)
        {
            return (T)repoObj;
        }

        // Not found or null; make one, add to dictionary cache, and return it.
        return MakeRepository<T>(factory, DbContext);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the dictionary of repository objects, keyed by repository type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Caller must know how to cast the repository object to a useful type.
    /// <p>This is an extension point. You can register fully made repositories here
    /// and they will be used instead of the ones this provider would otherwise create.</p>
    /// </remarks>
    protected Dictionary<Type, object> Repositories { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>Make a repository of type T.</summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of repository to make.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="dbContext">
    /// The <see cref="DbContext"/> with which to initialize the repository.
    /// </param>        
    /// <param name="factory">
    /// Factory with <see cref="DbContext"/> argument. Used to make the repository.
    /// If null, gets factory from <see cref="_repositoryFactories"/>.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected virtual T MakeRepository<T>(Func<DbContext, object> factory, DbContext dbContext)
    {
        var f = factory ?? _repositoryFactories.GetRepositoryFactory<T>();
        if (f == null)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("No factory for repository type, " + typeof(T).FullName);
        }
        var repo = (T)f(dbContext);
        Repositories[typeof(T)] = repo;
        return repo;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the repository for type T that this provider should return.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Plug in a custom repository if you don't want this provider to create one.
    /// Useful in testing and when developing without a backend
    /// implementation of the object returned by a repository of type T.
    /// </remarks>
    public void SetRepository<T>(T repository)
    {
        Repositories[typeof(T)] = repository;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="RepositoryFactories"/> with which to create a new repository.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Should be initialized by constructor injection
    /// </remarks>
    private RepositoryFactories _repositoryFactories;

}
```

Is this something that I could use Unity for and if so can someone give me some hints on how I could create the repositories in Unity so that that they could be shared. Note that I have two types of repositories. A generic and a custom. Right now these are returned using GetStandardRepo and GetRepo. I would like if possible to have the mapping that decideds which repo I get inside my Unity config file so that it's clearly visible.

Here is the Unity Config I have so far:

```
        container.RegisterType<RepositoryFactories>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IRepositoryProvider, RepositoryProvider>();
        container.RegisterType<IUow, Uow>();
        container.RegisterType<Contracts.Services.IContentService, Services.ContentService>();
        container.RegisterType<IAnswerService, AnswerService>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unity supports registering components "Per Request" in MVC projects. The first time a particular repository is served from the container it will be instantiated. Any subsequent requests for that repository during the same HTTP request will use this same repository rather than creating a new one.

You can read more about how this works using the link below.  Basically, you're looking to control the lifetime scope of your objects as a singleton rather than for each dependency.

[Unity Documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx#sec38)